# GNU Screen capturing <esc> key?

Tags: keyboard, vim, gnu-screen

GNU `screen` is capturing my <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, causing problems with `vim`.

Is there any way to change that behaviour in `screen`? I believe it enters the command mode, however, I can do that with <kbd>C-a:</kbd> anyway.

This is not the same as <kbd>C-a</kbd>, which I have already mapped to something. I am talking about the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key on the keyboard.

I tried `maptimeout 5` from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/gnu-screen-makes-vim-esc-key-slow) question but that doesn't help. I think it is similar to `tmux`, where I can do the following fix:

```
set -s escape-time 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GNU Screen` was working fine. The following `vim` option was the problem:

`set mouse=a`

In general, such issues could be related to `vim` configuration as well. Try to use a minimal `vimrc` and see if the issue happens.

Comment: i fixed it by clearing the `mouse` variable: `set mouse=` (of course, i don't use a mouse in vim)

Answer (score 2):

It's a screen bug with mouse events, not vim. You can use an older version and it will work fine.

https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?57748

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

From what I experience, I have to press the  <kbd>ESC</kbd>  key twice to switch modes in `vim` when inside `screen` and mouse mode is active. However, when I either switch mouse mode off or run `vim` outside screen this is not an issue anymore. I do not know what causes this behavior or how to resolve it.